# Can I use Session Object and Session ID in REST API and RectJS for authentication?

Tags: reactjs, spring, rest, spring-mvc

We want to migrate our existing web application( based on HTTP API) to REST Service model with ReactJS for UI. We have used Session object heavily (to hold data and process) in our current application. Is it possible to use same Session object to hold data and Session ID for authentication process  with REST API + ReactJS ?

Comment: If your ReactJS frontend is the only consumer of your "REST API", going for REST (in its true sense) is overkill. REST is designed for areas where you have lots of different clients not under your control but want to maintain the freedom to evolve your application domain in future. This is, unfortunately, only possible if you achieve true decoupling which is only achieved if you adhere to the imposed constraints. HATEOAS i.e. is one of these that describes the interaction concept to use which relies heavily on links, link-relations and form-based representation to teach clients what they need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and no.

A session is held for a specific HTTP client (say, your web browser) based on a cookie that's sent with every browser requests. It doesn't matter if that browser request is for a HTML web page (your current web app) or to a URL that returns JSON (such as an API). As such, you can refactor parts of your application front end to use the same session based auth (assuming things like domains and paths for your session cookie allow, etc).

Your refactored front end can therefore simply make an HTTP call to retrieve data and your backend can respond accordingly, using the data stored in the session on the server.

This does imply that you'll need to think about your resource abstraction in your API carefully because you cannot simply access your server session data in your JavaScript.

As time goes on you may find you want to refactor your authentication/session layer away from sessions w/ cookies and look at a proper IDS w/ JWT's in local storage but thats well beyond the scope of "can I do it this way".